# Multidimension array in perl

Tags: perl

I am working on a short script in which two to three variables are linked with each other.

```
Example:

my @batch;
my @case;
my @type = {
    back => "sticker",
    front => "no sticker",
    };
for (my $i=0; $i<$#batch; $i++{
  for (my $j=0; $j<$#batch; $j++{
    if ($batch[$i]=="health" && $case[$i]$j]=="pain"){
      $type[$i][$j]->back = "checked";
    }
  }
}
```

In this short code I want to use `@type` as `$type[$i][$j]->back & $type[$i][$j]->front`, but I am getting error that array referenced not defined . Can anyone help me how to fix this ?

Comment: Your mixing things incorrectly Your using a hash on an array and your not building your array correctly.  You need to go read about Perl data types, I also recommend the Perl cookbook.

Comment: You're using `==` instead of `eq` for string comparison.  Your using of `->back` wrong.  Currently `@type` is only an array of hashrefs, so at most you could do `$type[$i]{back}`.  But there really are too many syntax errors and not enough code for us to be able to decypher what you're real intent is.

Comment: @alexmac: I read some tutorials on perl data types but I couldn't find any link to understand this thing , can you give me any link if possible 

@ Mille: Is there any possiblity I could do `$type[$i][$j]->back` ? I mean how can I define my `@type` to do this ? 

sorry for errors I am new to perl

Comment: I could repost as an answer but if you look [Perl Data Types and Complex Data](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/perl-complex-data-structures/), I am new so not sure what the policy is on making a copy pretty much verbatim , also know its not part of the culture to provide just a link, damned either way?

Comment: Your welcome, Perl is different than other script languages in that data types are not classic int, float, etc.. I'd really if I was yourself back up and look at the data types in perl scalar, array, hash, type globe and then move forward to the link I gave.

Comment: The code you have posted won't compile. Please *always* post code that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl two-dimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays: each element of the top level array contains a (reference to) another array. The best reference for this is [perldoc `perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

From what I can understand, you want an array of arrays of hashes. `$type[$i][$j]->back` and `$type[$i][$j]->front` are method calls in Perl, and what you want is `$type[$i][$j]{back}` and `$type[$i][$j]{front}`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @batch;
my @case;

# Populate @batch and @case

my @type;

for my $i (0 .. $#batch) {
  for my $j (0 .. $#{ $batch[$i] } ) {
    if ($batch[$i] eq 'health' and $case[$i][$j] eq 'pain') {
      $type[$i][$j]{back} = 'checked';
    }
  }
}
```

But I am very worried about your design. `@type` will be full of undefined elements, with only occasional ones set to `checked`. A proper fix depends entirely on what you need to do with `@type` once you have built it.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Perl doesn't have multiple dimension variables. To emulate multidimential arrays, you can use what are called [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). A reference is a way of referring to a memory location of another Perl structure such as an array or hash.

References allows you to build up more complex structures. For example, you could have an array and instead of each element in the array having a distinct value, it could point to another array. Using this, I can treat my array of arrays as a two dimensional array. ***But it's not a two dimensional array***.

In a two dimensional array, each column (`$j`) has the same length. That's guaranteed. In Perl, what you have is each row (`$i`), pointing to a different array of columns (`$j`), and each of those column arrays could have a different number of elements (or even none at all! That inner array `$j` may not even be defined!).

There for, I have to check each column and see exactly how many values it might have:

```
for my $i ( 0..$#array ) {
    if ( ref $array[i] ne "ARRAY" ) {
       die qq(There is no sub array! for \$array[$i]!\n);
    }
    my @temp_j_array = @{ $array[$i] } {   # This is how you dereference a reference
    for my $j ( 0..$#temp_j_array ) {
       # Here be dragons...
    }
}
```

Note that I have to see exactly how many columns are in my inner (`$j`) array before I can go through it.

By the way, notice how I use `..` to index my arrays. It's a lot cleaner than using that three part `for` loop which is very error prone. For example, should you check `$i < $#array` or $i <= $#array`? See the difference?

Since you're already dealing with a very complex structure (an array of arrays), I'm going to make it even more complex: (An array of arrays of hashes). This added complexity allows me to get rid of three separate variables. Instead of trying to keep `@batch` `@case` and `@type` in sync with each other, I can make these keys to my inner most hash:

```
my @structure = ... # Some sort of structure...
for my $i ( 0..$#structure ) {
    my @temp = @{ $structure[$i] };   # This is a reference to an array. Dereference it.
    for my $j ( 0..$#temp ) {
        if ( $structure[$i]->[$j]->{batch} eq "health" 
                and $structure[$i]->[$j]->{case} eq "pain" ) {
                   $structure[$i]->[$j]->{back} = "checked";
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very common way to use Perl references to build more complex data structures:

```
my %employees;   # Keyed by employee number:

$employees{1001}->{NAME} = "Bob";
$employees{1001}->{JOB}  = "Yes man";
$employees{1002}->{NAME} = "Susan";
$employees{1002}->{JOB}  = "sycophant";
```

You had some syntax errors, and were using the wrong boolean operator (==) instead of (ne).

Comment: It's a shame that so many people apologize for Perl's lack of support for multi-dimensional arrays. Programming languages are all about abstractions, and Perl supports arrays of arrays to any level. How would it be different if it *really* supported multiple dimensions?

Comment: I'm not apologizing. It's an important destination and one that gets people in trouble. If I declare a 8 x 10 array. I know that $element[8,10] exists (even if the value is undefined), and I know that $element[2,12] doesn't. This isn't true in Perl. I might have $element[2]->[12]. I may not have $element[2]->[10] because $element[2] might not contain a reference, but scalar data. I like the endless flexibility of the complexity of data structure that Perl offers. However, references can be confusing. It's important to know what you're referring to in order to keep the syntax straight.